getFeeForMessage returning only base fee
import * as buffer from "buffer";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
   Connection, 
   PublicKey, 
   Transaction, 
   SystemProgram, 
   Keypair, 
   LAMPORTS_PER_SOL 
} from '@solana/web3.js';

window.Buffer = buffer.Buffer;

const SolanaGasEstimator = () => {
  const [feeEstimate, setFeeEstimate] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

   async function estimateFee() {
    try{
      // Create a connection to the Solana devnet
      const connection = new Connection(
         'https://api.devnet.solana.com', 'confirmed'
      );
    
      const senderKeypair = Keypair.generate();
      const sender2Keypair = Keypair.generate();

      const senderPublicKey = senderKeypair.publicKey;
      // Create a simple transaction
      // console.log("address", senderPublicKey.toString());
   
      const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: senderPublicKey,
          toPubkey: new PublicKey(
              '14ZrQyNLtAQdjJuAaAYmEbzVPkN5pjZkXbvWcA4CkAjo'
          ),
          // Example lamports amount to transfer
          lamports: 0.1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        })
      ); 
    
      transaction.feePayer = senderPublicKey;
    
      // Get the estimated fee for the transaction
      let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
      transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
      transaction.partialSign([senderKeypair,sender2Keypair]);
    
      // transaction.verifySignatures(true);
      const feePerSignature = await connection.getFeeForMessage(
         transaction.compileMessage(), 
         'processed'
      );
      const numberOfSignatures = transaction.signatures.length;
      const fee = feePerSignature.value * numberOfSignatures;
      const transactionSize = transaction.serializeMessage().length;

      // const fee = transaction.compileMessage();
      // setFeeEstimate(transaction.getEstimatedFee);
      // transaction.

      console.log("fee", fee);
      // const {value: fees} = await 
      connection.simulateTransaction(transaction);
      // console.log("fee", fees.unitsConsumed * fee);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error estimating fee:', error);
        setFeeEstimate('Error estimating fee');
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
  };

estimateFee();

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Solana Gas Fee Estimator</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Estimating fee...</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Estimated Fee: {feeEstimate ? `${feeEstimate} lamports` : 'Error estimating fee'}</p>
      )}
      <button onClick={estimateFee}>Re-estimate Fee</button>
   </div>
 );
};

export default SolanaGasEstimator;

